# BASH string parsing

Tags: bash, shell

I need to write a script to perform some magic on a long string and change the output.  I can easily do most of the scripting except for one part.

If I have a bash script that has

```
data = “CRITICAL - mempool lsmpi_io usage is 99.99%, mempool Processor usage is 34.38% | 'Processor_usage'=34.38%;80;90 'lsmpi_io_usage'=99.99%;80;90”
```

I need the information that always comes after "'Processor_usage'="

What commands do I need to do to make

```
$p=34.38
$w=80
$c=90
```

Keeping in mind that the percent could be just a single digit.

Comment: Is that really a bash script or the whole line is data itself? Having spaces around `=` in Bash with assignments causes syntax error.

Comment: Just curious, why do you need to parse the output of a nagios plugin using bash?

Comment: Adrian, because the plugin's author is not responding and I can't edit it as it is thousands of lines of code and have no clue where to start on it.  This reply is for a very specific router memory usage.  We only have 4 of them and the lsmpi_io pool is always at 100% usage, so the plugin results were useless for these 4 routers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Pure bash solution:

```
data=${data##*\'Processor_usage\'=}
data=${data%% *}
IFS=';' read p w c <<< "$data"


echo "p=${p%\%}" # or echo "p=${p:0:-1}"
echo "w=$w"
echo "c=$c"
```

Would output this:

```
p=34.38
w=80
c=90
```

Comment: I wonder what the OP actually meant about "Keeping in mind that the percent could be just a single digit.". That could actually affect how one decide if we have to exclude the last character or not. Nevertheless I think using an array is not necessary. you could just have `read p w c < ...` and `p=${p%'%'}`.

Comment: I was also concerned if file.txt would have had more data other than just `*Processor_usage*`. If that was the case we should filter it to only have that line in which it would be impractical to have it purely with bash.

Comment: @konsolebox
Yeah, you're right, I have almost finished editing it when I saw your comment. But I disagree about ``p=${p%'%'}``. Substring looks simplier and works better :)

Comment: @konsolebox oh yeah, I assume that ``data`` must be predefined somewhere else.

Comment: But what if there are occasions where there are no `%` in it?

Comment: I just pointed that out as I suck with parsing variables like this :)  I will test this later tonight or tomorrow at work and will reply.  Appreciate the help!!

Comment: Again, thanks for the help, just tested and wrote the remaining part of the script that I needed.  Feel my headache going away already!

Answer (score 4):

Bash has built-in regular expression support; there's absolutely no reason to use external tools such as sed.

```
data="CRITICAL - mempool lsmpi_io usage is 99.99%, mempool Processor usage is 34.38% | 'Processor_usage'=34.38%;80;90 'lsmpi_io_usage'=99.99%;80;90"
data_re="'Processor_usage'=([0-9.]+)%?;([0-9.]+)%?;([0-9.]+)%?"
if [[ $data =~ $data_re ]]; then
  p=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
  w=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
  c=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
fi
```

Comment: Interesting usage of BASH_REMATCH. Should be useful if version of Bash is 4.0 or newer. You should still trim out the '%' sign though as required by the OP. Sed was actually meant to be used if data was part of a multiple lined file. Also, for compatibility parameter replacements and `read` would be a better alternative.

Comment: @konsolebox Updated to trim the `%` characters. `BASH_REMATCH` is available in bash 3.x, and this particular usage pattern is supported all the way back to 3.0, so this is _not_ 4.x-specific.

Comment: Only that implementation of `=~` varies from version to version. At least 4.0+ has become more stable perhaps. Doing `[[ A =~ (A) ]]` would cause syntax error in earlier versions and quoted patterns like '(A)' which should have been literal strings are interpreted as regex instead. Perhaps storing the pattern on a variable would fix it, but because of that requirement I find extended patterns to be better, and never really rely on =~ unless it's for 4.0+. I actually thought that BASH_REMATCH didn't work because of it so I said 4.0.

Comment: @konsolebox the syntax I used was intentionally chosen to be supported back to 3.0. (Changes in the 3.x series impact behavior when a literal regex or a quoted variable is on the right-hand side of the operator -- but an unquoted parameter expansion all the way back).

Answer (score 0):

You could use for example sed. Follows an example to tokenize the string you pointed:

```
#!/bin/sh

DATA="CRITICAL - mempool lsmpi_io usage is 99.99%, mempool Processor usage is 34.38% | 'Processor_usage'=34.38%;80;90 'lsmpi_io_usage'=99.99%;80;90"

echo "$DATA" | sed "s@.*'Processor_usage'=\([0-9.]*\)%;\([0-9.]*\);\([0-9.]*\) .*@\1 \2 \3@" | while read p w c; do
    echo p=$p
    echo w=$w
    echo c=$c
done
```

Comment: -1 for use of `echo $DATA` (which string-splits and glob-expands content when forming arguments to `echo`, and thus modifies the data as it's passing through). `echo "$DATA"` would be less incorrect, even if still unnecessarily inefficient.

Comment: Also, there's no reason whatsoever to make this an environment variable inherited by subprocesses; if you left out the `export` (and, by convention, made the variable name lowercase), that would make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

If this text is in a file:

```
data = “CRITICAL - mempool lsmpi_io usage is 99.99%, mempool Processor usage is 34.38% | 'Processor_usage'=34.38%;80;90 'lsmpi_io_usage'=99.99%;80;90”
```

This command would get your requirements:

```
IFS=';' read p w c < <(sed -n "/Processor_usage/{ s|.*'Processor_usage'=||; s| .*||; s|%||g; p; }" file)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
read p w c < <(grep -oP "(?<='Processor_usage'=)[^\s]+" <<< $data | tr ';' ' ')

echo -e "p=${p}\nw=${w}\nc=${c}"
p=34.38%
w=80
c=90
```